# Is "at least" a conjuctive adverb? Can it be used in the middle of a sentence separated with two commas?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, adverbs

For example, this sentence:

It takes ten years to grow a tree, at least, that is what my father said.

Is this grammatically correct? Or is it a conjuctive adverb and then should be used as:

It takes ten years to grow a tree; at least, that is what my father said.

Not wondering which one sounds better. Only wondering if the first one is technically grammatically correct.

Comment: The first example leaves me pondering whether the "at least" applies to the ten years it takes to grow a tree or to what the father said.

Comment: << It takes ten years to grow a tree; at least, that is what my father said. >> Is the version where 'at least' is modal (concessive: conveying some doubt about the correctness of _my father_'s assertion). Whichever is intended, the comma splice is probably best considered unacceptable in this example.

Comment: Agreed. The present version needs corrective surgery or the ambiguity will be unresolvable.